# .mp3 file becomes unreadable after upload

Tags: php

So I'm busy on a form, where people fill in some details, and upload a .mp3 file. Seems quite easy:

```
define ('SITE_ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
$uploaddir = SITE_ROOT . '/uploads/mp3s/';
$file = basename($_FILES['stemopname']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['stemopname']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
```

So I tried to use it, uploaded a file, worked like a charm. The only thing is, after the file is moved, it's unreadable. So non of my default mp3 players (iTunes, WMP & VLC) can read it...

Did I do anything wrong with the script?

Thanks

Comment: @Stacker-flow Isn't that something completely different?

Comment: is the file in the temporary upload folder working? (path: `$_FILES['stemopname']['name']`) (remove the move_uploaded_file method and test it) I assume your file is already corrupted when it has been uploaded.

Comment: @dognose There is a tmp file in the path, and the file isn't corrupt before upload.